# Fail to load namespace Spring Security http://www.springframework.org/security/tags

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a problem with the namespace of spring security on my xhtml page. I don't understand why can't load the URI, and I have the following issue:

**Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Tue Jul 21 16:58:12 UTC 2015
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).**

Please i need a help! It is possible that the URI has been changed?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an incorrect namespace url. The correct URL is http://www.springframework.org/schema/security

The error page you are seeing is from the spring source website since it does not recognize the url. Try visiting http://www.springsource.org/security/tags in your browser

**Update**: for spring security tags used in jsp page the correct tag lib [declaration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html) is:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem doesn't in the spring security's context.xml. The problem, is in my xhtml file, when i want to use the taglibs in my page, show like:  xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"

Comment: Updated answer for taglib url

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't edit my post...........Thanks but when i want to use that taglibs in my page, show like:  xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags", it's the same to jsp page like you show me, but i think that move the URL :S you don't have the same problem when you want to access to that URL?

Comment: You can't use taglibs in an html page, it needs to be a jsp page

Comment: Yes, I can use it in xhtml, i don't use it in a html page, the problem is not the page, the problem is the link. If you want to access to the URI in JSP page, you have the same error.

Comment: The extension does not matter (jsp, html, xthml etc). For using tag libraries you need the page to be processed by your servers jsp engine and not as a static resource. The url gives a namespace to the tag library and its ok even if there is no relevant content on the URL. See example here on how spring taglibs are used: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html and this for an introduction to JSP tag libs: http://www.developer.com/java/ejb/article.php/1447551/An-Introduction-to-JSP-Standard-Template-Library-JSTL.htm